# How to read image from whatsapp notification

Tags: java, android

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);

                    Uri uri = getImageUri(context, bmp);
                    String imageMessage = "Image";
                    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("ImgMsg");
                    msgrcv.putExtra("uri", uri.toString());
                    msgrcv.putExtra("imageMessage", imageMessage);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
```

The code is here I used but it didn't work for me. Can anyone please tell me how to read images from whtsapp notification?? It would be a great help.. Thanks in advance..